# Managing CStringArray entries

Tags: string, mfc

This is in the context of a Visual Studio MFC application.

The `CStringArray::Add()` member takes an `LPCTSTR` argument. If I use a `CString` argument, I presume the argument is implicitly converted to `LPCTSTR` for `Add()` by the `LPCTSTR` operator of `CString`, so if I have a `CStringArray arr` and a `CString s` and call `arr.Add(s)`, this is exactly the same as calling `arr.Add((LPCTSTR)s)`, right?

So when `Add()` is called, does `CStringArray` simply store the passed pointer, or does it make a separate copy of the the string and store that? I'm asking because I wonder if I have to make a persistent string when I add it, or if my string can be deleted after it is added. For example, which if any of `foo1()`, `foo2()`, or `foo3()` is correct in the following?

```
class MyClass :
{
    ...
    CStringArray arr;
    CString mystr;
    void foo1() { arr.Add(_T("Bippety")); }
    void foo2() { CString s(_T("Boppety"); arr.Add(s); }
    void foo3() { mystr = _T("Boop"); arr.Add(mystr); }
    ...
};
```

The thing that worries me is that after `foo1()` and `foo2()` return, the passed argument goes out of scope and is deleted. Does the array then hold its own copy, or does it hold an invalid pointer?

Is the data stored in the `CStringArray` as just a pointer, or does it actually even go so far as to create a `CString` when `Add()` is called?

Finally, if I'm passing `LPCTSTR` to add, then I assume that if I created the string by a call to `new` to add it, then I'm surely responsible for `delete`ing it before `CStringArray` is destroyed, right?

I just can't quite see how the `LPCTSTR` can survive in the `CStringArray` when it's only a local string.

Comment: Why don't you debug into the Add call? This will take you into the source code.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle : I didn't know the source code was available. I thought it was just a library.

Comment: If you use debug mode then it will step into the source files.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle : Okay, very nice. I see that it eventually ends up using `memcpy()` to make a private copy of the string that is pointed to by the argument. That answers everything, thanks. +1 for you.

Comment: A debug configuration is not a strict requirement to single-step into MFC's source code. Microsoft host debug symbols for the MFC release builds on their public symbol servers as well.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CStringArray` is an MFC type array that stores C`String`'s. If you compile with Unicode, the `CString` is a `CStringW` and if you compile for MBCS, the `CString` is a `CStringA`.

The point of the class is that you do not have to worry so much about memory management. It does it for you. When you pass an `LPCTSTR` type string to the array, it constructs a `CString` object and adds it to the array. When the `CStringArray` object goes out of scope and/or its destructor gets called, all the CStrings it is holding onto will be cleaned up.

However, there is a caveat...

The `CString` class is reference counted more or less. It has an internal class such that when you make a copy of a class, it doesn't copy all of the data. Instead, it adds a reference to some of the internal structures and uses that. If you do some operation that changes the data, then it detaches itself from the reference and sets up its own new data structures. You have to step through the code to see this.

Now, the `CStringArray` has two `Add()` methods. One takes an `LPCTSTR` the other a c`onst CString&`. The second one makes a copy of `CString` doing the quasi reference counting mentioned in the previous paragraph.

That is just added information. You really don't need to worry about memory management too hard with the `CStringArray`. It does the heavy lifting for you.

The only part where you have to worry about `CString` reference counting is if you do stupid stuff and ignore const.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

CString s("HERE is my string\n");
CStringArray sArray;
sArray.Add(s);
sArray.Add(s);

_tprintf((LPCTSTR) s);  // "HERE is my string"
_tprintf((LPCTSTR) sArray[0]); // "HERE is my string"
_tprintf((LPCTSTR) sArray[1]); // "HERE is my string"

sArray[0].MakeLower();

_tprintf((LPCTSTR) s);  // "HERE is my string"
_tprintf((LPCTSTR) sArray[0]); // "here is my string"
_tprintf((LPCTSTR) sArray[1]); // "HERE is my string"

LPCTSTR lpsz = sArray[1];
_tcsupr((LPTSTR) lpsz); // don't do it!!!, also changes s!!!


_tprintf((LPCTSTR) s);  // "HERE IS MY STRING"
_tprintf((LPCTSTR) sArray[0]); // "here is my string"
_tprintf((LPCTSTR) sArray[1]); // "HERE IS MY STRING"

}
```

If you look at the printout from the third grouping, you see that we violated const-ness when we cast lpsz to a non-const string for the call to `_tcsupr` (`strupr`). Because of the way MFC reference counts strings, the "s" string contents were also effected. In the case of the second grouping calling the `MakeLower()` member function of `CString`, only that particular string was effected.

This is more than you asked. Maybe it will be helpful to people.

Comment: The `CStringT` class template has a dedicated interface for modifying and updating the internal character buffer (`GetBuffer()` and friends). If you use `CStringT` outside its specification, anything goes. Since there is no striking reason to do so, the solution is simple: Don't.

Comment: I had to fix a bug from a colleague at work after he left. He cast away the const-ness of a string to pass to an API that took LPTSTR...and what do you know...it introduced a bug...shocker right?